# Mention multiple path based on existence in Linux

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have two different servers - core and bpm. I will be writing common script. In this case the path just varies on the name of the server as,

In Core server --> /apps/core/SharedLib/
and

In BPM server --> /apps/bpm/SharedLib/

So i have to mention path in same line and the server should decide based on the paths existence.

So i need something like,

```
cd /apps/<core|bpm>/SharedLib/
```

How to mention it in correct way?

Comment: create softlink to /apps//SharedLib/ and use this path on both server

Comment: Is this directory the only thing that changes depending on which server you're on? Otherwise it looks like you might benefit from sourcing a configuration file which could set a few variables such as the server's root directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved similar problem with my servers using syntax: `cd /apps/*/SharedLib/`

**Explanation:**

`*` is wildcard character for bash. It's a regular expression. It looks for all the directories which is inside `/apps` but selects only that sub directory which has `SharedLib` inside it. You can run `ls /apps/*` and other `ls` commands to understand it's functionality completely

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

if `hostname` command returns the server names as it appears in your dir structure, you could also do

```
cd /apps/$(hostname)/SharedLib/
```

Otherwise you could also simply have a variable with the actual host name in your script and use the variable in your cd command :

```
cd /apps/$your_var/SharedLib/
```

Comment: No, it doesn't go with Hostname